# Install Active Directory PowerShell module on Windows Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to install the AD PowerShell module on Windows Server 2012 but I can't afford for the server to restart during business hours.

My question is can the AD module be installed from Add/Remove Windows Features without requiring a restart?

If so which AD Modules are required (minimum) for PowerShell to run this command

```
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut
```

Comment: you can also do this from a client with the RSAT rather than logging into the DC directly

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can install and use with no reboot required.

```
Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell
```

Also I want to be clear that this is only for installing the Powershell module. Not all of Active Directory in its entirety. Installing Active Directory is an entirely different thing.

Comment: Yes. It is identical to what Server Manager runs in the background. It just requires fewer mouse clicks.

Comment: Note - You may need to call `Import-Module ServerManager` first in order to load the `Install-WindowsFeature` command.